# How to fetch 3 filed value from a table based on not null condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have 3 fields a,b,c(atleast one field is not null) in a table TABLE.For a record I have to fetch a,b,c in the format "  a or b or c " if a,b,c are not null and " a or b" if c is null and only c if a and b are null.Please help me with query

Comment: Means one column null should be allowed in result??

Comment: You'll probably use CASE, IS NOT NULL, and CONCAT (||).

Comment: can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nvl2(a, a||' or ', '')||nvl2(b, b||' or ', '')||nvl2(c, c, '')
 FROM ( -- casos de uso
--      select NULL        a, NULL        b, NULL        c from dual union all
        select NULL        a, NULL        b, 'no-nulo-c' c from dual union all
        select NULL        a, 'no-nulo-b' b, NULL        c from dual union all
        select NULL        a, 'no-nulo-b' b, 'no-nulo-c' c from dual union all
        select 'no-nulo-a' a, NULL        b, NULL        c from dual union all
        select 'no-nulo-a' a, NULL        b, 'no-nulo-c' c from dual union all
        select 'no-nulo-a' a, 'no-nulo-b' b, NULL        c from dual union all
        select 'no-nulo-a' a, 'no-nulo-b' b, 'no-nulo-c' c from dual
      );
```

I comment the first case because you say "at least one field is not null".